# How to manipulate the pixels inside a bounding box drawn using minAreaRect() in opencv - python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have an image with few green bars. But one of them are special because it's connected to a blue colored shape. I want to draw a bounding box using minAreaRect() around the special green bar.

I was able to draw bounding boxes using minAreaRect() around all the green bars so far. But in order to filter the green bars and take only the special one, I need to identify which box contains the blue pixels.

In order to do that, I want to check every pixel inside every box to check which one contains blue pixels. Is there any way to identify the pixel coordinates of the pixels inside a bounding box. Or is there a better approach ?

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Load the aerial image and convert to HSV colourspace
image = cv.imread("1.png")
image1 = image
hsv = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Define lower and uppper limits of the color blue
low_blue = np.array([94, 80, 2])
high_blue = np.array([126, 255, 255])

# Mask image to only select blues
mask1 = cv.inRange(hsv, low_blue, high_blue)

# Change image to green where we found blue
image[mask1 > 0] = (0, 130, 0)


blurred_frame = cv.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 0)
hsv = cv.cvtColor(blurred_frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
low_green = np.array([25, 52, 72])
high_green = np.array([102, 255, 255])
mask = cv.inRange(hsv, low_green, high_green)
_, contours, _ = cv.findContours(mask, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
image[mask1 > 0] = (255, 0, 0)

for contour in contours:

    rect = cv.minAreaRect(contour)
    box = cv.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    Cx = rect[0][0]
    Cy = rect[0][1]

    cv.drawContours(image, [box], 0, (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv.imshow("Frame", image)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the input image

https://ibb.co/h9cv4DN

Here is the expected output (bounding box indicated with purple color)

https://ibb.co/8Mq6Mwt

Comment: Can you post the code that draws rectangles around all of the green bars?

Comment: @StephenMeschke I have updated the question with the code I have tried. Please check. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer looks at all the green bars in the image. It check if the green bar also contains a blue color.

```
for contour in contours:

    rect = cv.minAreaRect(contour)
    box = cv.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    Cx = rect[0][0]
    Cy = rect[0][1]

    # Make a mask of this single green line
    mask = np.zeros_like(mask1)
    cv.drawContours(mask, [contour], 0, 255, cv.FILLED)
    sigle_green_line = cv.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)
    sigle_green_line = cv.cvtColor(sigle_green_line, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # Check how much blue is in the image
    blue_mask = cv.inRange(sigle_green_line, low_blue, high_blue)
    print(sum(sum(blue_mask)))
    # If the image is not all black (all zeros) the contour contains some blue
    if sum(sum(blue_mask)) > 0: print('This contour contains some blue')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I was previously able to solve the problem by taking the center pixels of each rectangle and compare their color to check which one contains blue. That logic work with my scenario because in my case, if a blue color exist it always in the middle of a green bar. But your logic is the perfect solution which can apply in other scenarios too. You saved the day.